# Merging remote content to local repo

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-remote

I am trying to clone a remote repo to my local workspace, and push the content to a new bare repo I set up to maintain, this repo need to have occasional updates from upstream repo, and new contents need to be pushed to local repo as well.

Here is a example:

```
git clone ssh://username@whatevergitrepo.com/project
```

and I created a bare repo as project_local

```
mkdir project_local.git
git init --bare --share=2 project_local.git
```

once the remote repo is cloned in my workspace, since this remote repo has multiple branches,

```
branch1
branch2
.
.
branchN
```

Here is what I have done to get all the branches from remote and push to my local bare repo.

```
cd project
git branch -a >&/tmp/branchinfo
sed s,.*/,, /tmp/branchinfo >&/tmp/branchinfo1                              #this remove everything before the last '/' before the actual name of the branch
for i in `cat /tmp/branchinfo1`; do git checkout $i; done                   #checkout all the branches from remote site.
for i in `cat /tmp/branchinfo1`; do git push project_local.git $i; done     # Push all the remote branches to local repo I created with all contents.
```

after this, the contents from remote repo are now in my local bare repo, but how can I fetch and merge all remote changes of individual branches to the corresponding branches in the local repo I created?

I have tried using 'git remote add' but that only does the fetch the refs, it doesn't actually do the merge content.

Thank you in advance for any help I can get.

Thanks

Comment: Did you do a pull after adding the remotes?  Also, if you have your remotes configured properly I believe all tracked branches will be pushed at the same time when you do a "git push"

Comment: I did a pull but it tells me something like not configured properly, and push didn't work, how can I set the config file properly, sorry if this question seems kinda stupid, but I am new to git.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

sounds like all you are doing is updating branches. There is no merge unless you are counting a fast-forward merge which is really just a reference update.

All you need to do is

```
git fetch original-repo
git branch -r | cut -f3- -d'/' | xargs -i{} git push new-repo original-repo/{}:{}
```

This assumes you already added a remote entry for your new repo and called it `new-repo`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give a try.

BTW, I have added the remote as upstream, doing 
 'git remote add upstream ssh://username@whatevergitrepo.com/project'